# How to validate Html forms in java app

Tags: javascript, java

Hello I have made a little scanning application, that scans a list of urls.
Now I want to make it work with urls, that need to be logged in, to show their content, so I have to fill some forms first.
Here is my code:

```
public class Scan1 {
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String urlforsearching = "https://www.facebook.com";
    URL oracle = new URL(urlforsearching);
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36"); 

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
 }
}
```

I have tried to log in with javascript comands on the google chrome console, and they work, but I do not know how to implement them in the java app.

```
document.getElementById('email').value="email"
document.getElementById('pass').value="pass"
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to manipulate the DOM tree of an HTML page via Java. Depending on your task, you can choose different alternatives to achieve what you strive for.

If your idea is to implement a web crawler style program, there is no need to actually fill in the form. You can just send a HTTP request to the form's target URL programmaticaly, supplying the right parameters. For example, if you have this form:

```
<form target="login">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

you need to send a request like this `<page root xml>/login?username=<some username>&password=<some password>`

This will have the same effect as filling in the form in the browser and submitting it.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: my idea is to get a full html code from the facebook`s graph search and scan it for my hot words, and repeat the graph search for a lisr of key words. when I open a graph search I need to scroll the page to the "End of results" to receive the full content of the html.

Comment: Why don't you use the Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api. It will be much, much easier.